# How to use Ajax in Laravel 8

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I tried to use Ajax from laravel, but I couldn't find I want it.

How to use ajax in Laravel?

in main.js file...

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url : "{{ route('saveToken') }}",
        data : {'token' : token},
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result){

            console.log("===== " + result + " =====");

        }
    });
```

in blade template ...

```
<body>
     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
     <div class="wrapper">
     @yield('content')
     <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>
     </div>                
</body>
```

php file

```
//web.php
Route::get('/saveToken', [FcmController::class, 'saveToken']);

// Fcm controller
public function saveToken(Request $request)
{
...
```

on using ajax url
//"{{ route('saveToken') }}"

```
~~~/%7B%7B%20route('saveToken')%20%7D%7D  404 not found
```

// '/saveToken'

```
405 not allowed
```

Comment: route defined get but in ajax you are trying to post method

Comment: you are using post method but on route you add it as get method

Comment: The not foud is probably because the helper [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) uses named routes, add to `->name('saveToken')` to the route.

Comment: You can not use Laravel helper/code in JavaScript file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your route

`Route::post('/saveToken', [FcmController::class, 'saveToken'])->name('saveToken');`

OR

Change your ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        url : "{{ url('saveToken') }}",
        data : {'token' : token},
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result){

            console.log("===== " + result + " =====");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling route name in url so you have to add route name in route .

```
Route::get('/saveToken', [FcmController::class, 'saveToken']);
```

Replace with

```
Route::post('/saveToken', [FcmController::class, 'saveToken'])->name('saveToken');
```